# how to set click counter in admob interstitial ad

Tags: counter, interstitial

I use the below code to show interstitial ad when clicking on a navigation menu item in my android app.But if I implement this code ad comes every time we click on the menu item.This will frustrate users.So how can I set a counter for this so that ad should come at second click on menu items and then for every 5 clicks etc.Any help would be most appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {

    // INTERSTITIAL AD IMPLEMENTATION 

            final InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID));
            AdRequest requestForInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(requestForInterstitial);
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    Log.i("log-", "INTERSTITIAL is loaded!");  if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        interstitialAd.show();  }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    Log.i("log-", "INTERSTITIAL is closed!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    Log .i("log-", "INTERSTITIAL failed to load! error code: " + errorCode);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    Log.i("log-", "INTERSTITIAL left application!");
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    Log.i("log-", "INTERSTITIAL is opened!");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Add your solution as answer so that it will helps other also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following code:

```
 if (counter == 4) {
    Log.i("log-", "INTERSTITIAL is loaded!");
    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    interstitialAd.show();
}
 counter = 1;
} 
 else {
 counter++;
}
```